# Different proguard outputs for identical inputs on two machines

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

Having built a release version of my app (on a Linux machine) I get an unexpected error on opening the app.

I build that same (release) build on a mac and there are no problems, using the same git tag. However, the output `mapping.txt` file is **different** on both machines. For a sanity check I diff the output of `./gradlew app:dependencies` on both machines - identical. `git log` on both machines shows the same: `commit bb70bcf36e8c0e1a3 etc etc`. `git status` shows only `app/build` and `build` untracked. It doesn't look as though there's anything relevant hidden by `.gitignore`.

So - I'm getting different outputs from proguard on what seem to be identical inputs on two different machines. Any idea what's going on? (I know I'm going to be typing D'oh tomorrow...)

ps. the generated apk files are different on both machines.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted `.gradle` dirs in both home and app directories on both machines. Now the app build on the linux box starts fine but generated (release) apks are still different on both machines (different SHA1 hashes). However, the apk sizes are very nearly the same..2264536 and 2264528 respectively and mapping.txt now the same...presumably apks **should** be identical generated on different platforms ?

And of course I don't know how the gradle caches contributed to the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the delete of the app .gradle directory. I had already deleted ~/.gradle/caches/ and that alone didn't fix it.